# How to redefine the URLs generation without changes at the HtmlHelper#link(...) calls in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, routes, url-routing, html-helper, cakephp-routing

I have a CakePHP website with many internal links, that are build with the `HtmlHelper`:

**/app/View/MyController/myaction.ctp**

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->link(
    $item['Search']['name'],
    array(
        'controller' => 'targetcontroller',
        'action' => 'targetaction',
        $profileId,
        $languageId
    )
);
?>
```

It works fine with the default route:

**/app/Config/routes.php**

```
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

The generated links look like that: `/mycontroller/myaction/$profileId/$languageId`.

Now I want to use search engine friendly URLs (with profile names and ISO-639-1 language codes instead of IDs) for a part of the website and added a new Route:

**/app/Config/routes.php**

```
Router::connect(
    '/:iso6391/:name.html',
    array('controller' => 'mycontroller', 'action' => 'myaction'),
    array(
        'iso6391' => '[a-zA-Z]+',
        'name' => '[0-9a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜ\-]+',
    )
);
```

And it also works fine and the incomming URIs like `/producer/en/TestName.html` are interpreted correctly.

But the `HtmlHelper` is still generating the old URIs like `/mycontroller/myaction/1/1`.

The [docu](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#reverse-routing) says:

> Reverse routing is a feature in CakePHP that is used to allow you to easily change your URL structure without having to modify all your code. By using routing arrays to define your URLs, you can later configure routes and the generated URLs will automatically update.

Well, the `HtmlHelper` gets a routing array as input, that means: I'm using the reverse routing.

Why does it not work? How to make the `HtmlHelper` generate the new URLs (without changing the `HtmlHelper#link(...)` calls)?

Answer (score 1):

**Bit of explanation first**

You are *technically* not using reverse routing. You see, the output link, `/mycontroller/myaction/1/1` definitively doesn't match `/iso/name.html`. Like, in no way. So, the routing skips that rule because it doesn't apply.

**Code**

Try this

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    $item['Search']['name'],
    array(
        'controller' => 'targetcontroller',
        'action' => 'targetaction',
        'iso6391' => $someStringWithIso,
        'name' => $someName
    )
);
```

But for that, you have to change your routing a bit, because you are not passing the parameters (check [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action) for examples)

```
Router::connect(
    '/:iso6391/:name.html',
    array('controller' => 'mycontroller', 'action' => 'myaction'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('iso6391', 'name'),
        'iso6391' => '[a-zA-Z]+',
        'name' => '[0-9a-zA-ZäöüßÄÖÜ\-]+',
    )
);
```

And you have to mind the first string match `/:iso6391/:name.html`. Do you want to match this route to every controller and action in your project, or just *the one* controller and *the one view*. If it is for all projects, just for precaution, use this

```
  /:controller/:action/:iso6391/:name.html
```

if is just for, say, Controller1 and action "view", use

```
  /controller1/view/:iso6391/:name.html
```

The detail you need to consider is the extension you use `.html`, is that really necessary in the url? If it is, add it as a parameter in the Html#link

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    $item['Search']['name'],
    array(
        'controller' => 'targetcontroller',
        'action' => 'targetaction',
        'iso6391' => $someStringWithIso,
        'name' => $someName

        'ext' => 'html'
    )
);
```

and also add `parseExtensions` to the routing file. [Read this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#file-extensions). Would be easier if you don't add the extension, but that's up to you.

In the end, you still have to change your calls to `Html->link`...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but, as you correctly say, with this solution "in the end, I still have to change my calls to Html->link". So thanks again, but it's not really a solution for this case.

Comment: @automatix There simply is no way around modifying your `HtmlHelper::link()` calls in one way or another, being it passing proper values for reverse routing directly, or using a custom helper that transforms the passed options, or whatever...